# Modify SSRS 2010 with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

I have to modify some reports SSRS, so I downloaded them and update them with Visual Studio 2017 (I have SSDT 2015 and SQL Server 2008).
Then when I wanted to upload them on the SSRS server, I have an error about the versions. So I checked the lines with notepad of the .rdl and they're in 2010.
I just notice that when I upload them in my SSRS project with Visual Studio, they change to 2016.
I don't achieve to create a SSRS project that allow the 2010 .rdl.. It always change them to 2016.
Did I have to use an older version of Visual Studio ?
2 days that I search and don't found .. :|
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Two things:
1)  Your project must specify the version if you are using the deploy option from visual studio.  This is found under properties for the project:
[image]

2)  If you are using the upload function from Report Manager, you need to use the file found in the bin\debug folder, not in the main folder of the project